# Java Script: loop through JSON

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

How would you loop through provided JSON to get every grade from  all the years and paste them in array?I'm quite new to JS so any explanation is welcome.
Expected array for this example would be [2,4,2,5,4,5,4.5,2,3.5,5,5,5,5,5]

```
{
    "first_name": "Ala",
    "last_name": "Kowalski",
    "birth_date": "29 AUG 1990",
    "indeks_number": "9454530",
    "year_of_study": "2",
    "courses": {
        "2013": {
            "AlgorithmsI": {
                "grades": {
                    "exercices": [
                        2,
                        4
                    ],
                    "lecture": [
                        2,
                        5
                    ]
                }
            },
            "BasicPhysicsI": {
                "grades": {
                    "exercices": [
                        4
                    ],
                    "lecture": [
                        5
                    ]
                }
            },
            "ProgrammingI": {
                "grades": {
                    "exercices": [
                        4.5
                    ],
                    "lecture": [
                        2,
                        3.5
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "2014": {
            "ProgrammingII": {
                "grades": {
                    "exercices": [
                        5
                    ],
                    "lecture": [
                        5
                    ]
                }
            },
            "BasicPhysicsII": {
                "grades": {
                    "exercices": [
                        5
                    ],
                    "lecture": [
                        5
                    ]
                }
            },
            "AlgorithmsII": {
                "grades": {
                    "exercices": [
                        5
                    ],
                    "lecture": [
                        5
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you can simple use [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might use `JSON.stringify` as a way to iterate through the object:

```
grades = [];
JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
    if (key === 'grades') 
        grades = grades.concat(value.exercices, value.lecture);
    return value;
});
```

#### How this works

`JSON.stringify` is designed to convert an object into a JSON string. To do that, it iterates over all values in the object at all levels. It also provides the ability to specify a `replacer` parameter, which is a function called with each key/value pair it encounters. Here, we use the `replacer` not to control the stringification, but to get a chance to examine each key/value pair to see if the key is `'grades'`, and if so add those grades to the `grades` array. We have to return `value` so that `JSON.stringify` keeps iterating. The actual result from `JSON.stringify` is irrelevant and thrown away.

Comment: Upvoted! This is such a fun, whimsical answer (and I today I learned that `stringify` accepts a `replacer` argument). I don't know if I personally would use this to iterate an object (`stringify` is slow enough as it is), but it definitely illustrates the ease of doing something in JS many different ways ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
var grades = [];
var obj = <your Object>;

processObj(obj);

function processObj(obj) {
    for (var n in obj) {
        if (n=='exercices' || n=='lectures') {
            for (var j=0;j<obj[n].length;j++) {
                grades.push(obj[n][j]);
            }
        } else {
            processObj(obj[n]);
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this one.

```
function looop(jsonob) {
    var gradeArray = [];
    for (years in jsonob.courses) {
        for (lessons in jsonob.courses[years]) {
            for (x in jsonob.courses[years][lessons].grades.exercices) {
                gradeArray.push(jsonob.courses[years][lessons].grades.exercices[x]);
            }
            for (x in jsonob.courses[years][lessons].grades.lecture) {
                gradeArray.push(jsonob.courses[years][lessons].grades.lecture[x]);
            }
        }
    }
    return gradeArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive:

```
function each(object, iterator) {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (key) {
        var value = object[key];
        iterator(value, key);
    });
}

function inArray(array, value) {
    return array.indexOf(value) > -1;
}

function isPlainObject(value) {
    return !!value && typeof value === 'object' && value.constructor === Object;
}

function getGrades(data) {
    var grades = [];
    each(data, function (value, key) {
        if (inArray(['exercices', 'lecture'], key)) {
            grades = grades.concat(value);
        } else if (isPlainObject(value)) {
            grades = grades.concat(getGrades(value));
        }
    });
    return grades;
}
```

You can test this in Node.js with:

```
var assert = require('assert');
assert.deepEqual(getGrades(fixture),
                 [2, 4, 2, 5, 4, 5, 4.5, 2, 3.5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]);
```

Where `fixture` is your JSON.